# How to plot a function of functions

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to get a plot like this

[image]

which is generated in Gnuplot but plotting from a file.

The Gnuplot scrip that contains all the functions is the following:

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set key right top font "Helvetica,17"
set ylabel "Received power, P_t (dBm)" font "Helvetica,18"
set xlabel "Separation distance, r (m)" font "Helvetica,18"
set xtics font "Helvetica,16"
set ytics font "Helvetica,16"
set size 1, 1.2
set terminal postscript color eps enhanced
set grid xtics ytics
set key spacing 1.5
set key box linestyle 1 width 3
set logscale x
set grid xtics mxtics
set output "link-up-test.eps"
h1=1.85
h2=0.5
r(x) = sqrt((h1 - h2)**2 + x**2 )
lmb = 300/865.7
H(x) = sqrt( 1- (4*h1*h2)/(x**2 + (h1 + h2)**2 ) )
theta(x) = 2*pi/lmb*( sqrt((h1 + h2)**2+x**2 ) - sqrt((h1 - h2)**2+ x**2) )
q_e(x) = H(x)**2*(sin(theta(x)))**2 + (1 - H(x)*cos(theta(x)))**2
P_x_G = 4
sigma = 1.94
invsqrt2pi = 0.398942280401433
normal(x,mu,sigma)=sigma<=0?1/0:invsqrt2pi/sigma*exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sigma)**2)
rnd(x) = 10**(-normal(x,0,sigma)/10)
pot_t(x) = 10*log10( 1000*(P_x_G*1.622*((300/lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*pi*r(x))**2) *1.2*1)*q_e(x)*rnd(x) )
plot [1:12][] pot_t(x) t "up"  w lines ls 1
```

With this script, I get the following plot

[image]

which is has similar form but it does not have the randomness os the function `rnd(x)` and it does not have the same levels in the y-axis.

I am missing something but I have checked several times the functions several times. I would like to know why is not the same figure.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give my solution to this question. 
I have used the Box-Muller method to generate Gaussian samples.

```
h1=1.85
h2=0.5
r(x) = sqrt((h1 - h2)**2 + x**2 )
lmb = 300/865.7
H(x) = sqrt( 1- (4*h1*h2)/(x**2 + (h1 + h2)**2 ) )
theta(x) = 2*pi/lmb*( sqrt((h1 + h2)**2+x**2 ) - sqrt((h1 - h2)**2 + x**2) )
q_e(x) = H(x)**2*(sin(theta(x)))**2 + (1 - H(x)*cos(theta(x)))**2
P_G = 4

sigma = 1.94


normal(x,mu,sigma) = sqrt(-2.0 * log(rand(0))) * cos(2*pi * rand(0)) * sigma + mu
rnd(x) = 10**(-normal(x,0,sigma)/10)

pot_t(x) = 10*log10( 1000*(P_G*1.622*((lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*pi*r(x))**2) *1.2*1)*q_e(x)*rnd(x) )
set samples 1000
plot [1:12][] pot_t(x) t "up"  w lines ls 1
```

Which creates this plot:

[image]
The samples are generated with the function `normal(x, mu, sigma)`.
There is only an issue with this solution
When I plot with `set logscale x` the plot of points should be denser when the `x-axis` are more concentrated (see first plot above), but it seems that Gnuplot first makes the logscale of the `x-axis` and after that takes equidistant samples in figure dealing the log scale as a linear scale. I would appreciate if anyone could answer this or improve the solution.

Regards

Comment: You can first create the data using a linear scale for the x axis and store the result in a data block, then switch to a logarithmic scale and plot the data block: `unset log x; set table $data; plot [1:12] pot_t(x) w lp; unset table; set log x; plot $data title "up"  w lines ls 1`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing random about your rnd(x) function. Just plot rnd(x) and you can see that. Why are you not using gnuplot's rand() function in conjunction with your normal distribution?

Comment: You are right. What I need is to generate random Gaussian numbers to add to each `y` number. Can Gnuplot generate random realizations of a Gaussian?.

Comment: Thank you. I think I fix the problem. I have generated the Gaussian with Box-Muller-Transform and works fine. I am going to delete this question because I think is not a real problem that could help anyone else. Regards

Comment: If you fixed the problem, post your own answer. I think generating Gaussian inside gnuplot would interest people.